# How to send notification e-mail when release doesn't succeed in Azure DevOps?

Tags: notifications, azure-devops

I try to send notification from Azure DevOps when a test fails in the release pipeline. If the test fails then the release pipeline has `Partialy succeeded` status.
I can't find option to notify when this pipeline fails in Azure.
**Question:** How to send notification e-mail when release doesn't succeed in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new release notification subscription for "A deployment is completed".  Add a new filter clause such that:

`Deployment Status = Partially succeeded`

or `Deployment Status = Failed`

If you want to treat a test failure as a failure and not a partial success, you will likely need to un-check the "Continue on error" option under "Control Options" of the test task in your release pipeline.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for it in the release definition, but notifications were in the Project settings.